# Setting default number of lines Vim displays

Tags: vim

I have a file which has 30 lines. After opening it with Vim, only the top 23 lines are displayed.
[image]

Here is my ~/.vimrc file

```
set expandtab
set ts=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set cindent
set smartindent
inoremap <C-F>      <C-X><C-F>
```

I use mac air default terminal.

Anyone knows how to set vim to display all the 30 lines by default?

Comment: how big is your terminal window?

Comment: `:set lines=40` sets the number of visible lines in a screen to 40. For me, 40 is the maximum size.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the default number of lines terminal shows...
[image]

Thanks to @kent